# What movie was this, with a wolf girl and neo-nazi midget?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a movie in the late 80's or early 90's on The Drive-in Channel I believe, on our satellite tv with the giant dish.

All I can remember is a naked, blonde, beautiful wolf/dog woman shows up, maybe washed up on shore, at a castle where a strange party or event is happening. She is greeted and shown around by a big haired, flamboyant, chisel faced actor (I remember him being pale). This may have been a musical, or partially.

The other part I remember was a midget Neo-Nazi that may have been supposed to be a faulty clone of Hitler, mustache and all. And I believe at one point he rode a giant plastic penis and went nuts.

Lots of nudity with beautiful people.

I almost think I'd categorize it as reminding me of German expressionism. Very bizarre yet very entertaining, especially when high. I would love to see this again. I have no idea what the name of it was, and no research on my own has helped. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Was this in the US and in English? Or was it a German (or other language) movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though the current answer is a good suggestion, it doesn't really follow the plot in the question. There is a very obscure cult film that *does*, though. It's called [Pandemonium](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093700/combined), a bizarre Australian exploitation comedy from 1987 in the vein of *The Rocky Horror Picture Show*.

In it, a feral, naked blonde **dingo girl** (she was raised by dingoes) emerges on a beach and heads to a big mansion-like place populated by bizarre characters, including a **small, insane Hitler clone named Little Adolf**. And unfortunately, a big phallic prop does come into play later on.

There are no clips available of this trippy oddity, but you can find more plot details and some pics in a couple of online reviews like [this one](http://mondoexploito.com/?p=11136) and [this one](http://taliesinttlg.blogspot.com/2008/10/honourable-mentions-pandemonium.html) **[Warning: Nudity]**. And you can scroll down to see a collection of images from it **[Warning: Nudity, Again]**:

> [image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: YES!! Pandemonium! I recognized the name as soon as I read it. Thank you so much for your answer. You've made my day!

Comment: @RW1020 No problem! :) Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it, this effectively resolves your question. And welcome to M&TV!